# Can you change the Noodle Curving behavior, particularly for left-directed connections, back to how it was in Blender version 3.1?

Tags: node-editor, interface, theme

In versions 3.1 of Blender and earlier, noodles connecting reroute nodes would end neatly right on those nodes, whether your theme's Noodle Curving was set to 0 for straight lines or higher for curved ones.

*Noodle curving set to 0 in Blender 3.1:*
[image: Noodle curving set to 0 in Blender 3.1]

*Noodle curving set to 7 in Blender 3.1:*
[image: Noodle curving set to 7 in Blender 3.1]

From version 3.2 onward this behavior has changed [as noted here](https://developer.blender.org/T98532). Noodes with curving above 0 now overextend when moving right-to-left, which makes it difficult to achieve clean node setups for complicated shaders.

*Noodle curving set to 7 in Blender 3.2:*
[image: Noodle curving set to 7 in Blender 3.2]

See in particular the left-directed straight line which now has a lip either side.

Is it possible to revert this behavior in newer releases of Blender?

Many thanks for your time!